# Controlar if y método replace en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un input donde ingreso datos y que los primeros 3 numeros son separados con un - y los siguientes 3 tambien y el resto no:

001-001-123234344

Lo que necesito es que ese input solo permita tener el - y no otro simbolo como {}()+*# ... ect

este es mi codigo

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.dato" ng-change="cambios()" maxlength="17"><br>
```

y en mi controller tengo lo siguiente

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.cambios = function(){
   if($scope.data.dato.length === 3 || $scope.data.dato.length === 7){
        $scope.data.dato = $scope.data.dato+'-';       
   }
   if($scope.data.dato.length === 17){
        $scope.final = $scope.data.dato.replace(/-/g,'');
        alert($scope.final)
    }
 }
```

finalmente en el primer if se agrega el -, cuando ya he ingresado todos los datos y quisiera borrar todo y quede vacio no se borra, como puedo controlar eso?

De antemano les agradezo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar Angular ui-mask

Aqui la liga para que sepas como usarlo y descargarlo https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask

Y aqui puedes verlo funcionando en linea: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html

pero prácticamente es definir la máscara en tu input de esta forma

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.dato" ui-mask="999-999-999999999"  ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="_"/>
```

Espero esto ayude.